# python redirect to another view

Tags: python, django, redirect

I want to redirect from a view to another view and passing data but no chance.
Here are my codes :

```
def affiche(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':                                     
        form = AfficheForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Select = form.cleaned_data['Select']
            if Select == '1':
                return redirect('affiche_all', devise='EURO')


def affiche_all(request, devise):
    data = websvc(devise)
    return render_to_response('affiche_all.html', {'data': data},
        RequestContext(request))
```

I'm new to django development, so i will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use reverse to build up your URL to redirect to:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def affiche(request):
    form = AfficheForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':     
        if form.is_valid():
            Select = form.cleaned_data['Select']
            if Select == '1':
                url = reverse('affiche_all', args=(),
                    kwargs={'devise': 'EURO'})
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

This assumes you have a named url pattern that accepts a keyword argument of 'devise', as such:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('your_app.views',
    url(r'^some-path/(?P<devise>[-\w]+)/$', 'affiche_all', name='affiche_all'),
)
```

That named parameter will look for one or more words and hypens, like a slug. You might want to change that to suit your needs.

Comment: what about url pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('affiche_all', devise=('EURO',)))
```